# jest.spyOn looks like its sharing context across multiple tests (in the same describe)

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, spyon

When I just run my individual test it works. When I run the whole file I get this error.
[image]

Let's say I have an entity called `Group`, Group has properties and methods. I'm trying to verify that these methods are called given the conditions scenario.

My guess is that im using jest.spyOn in the wrong way. `Group.prototype` works, but when I have multiple tests running, looks like if test A executes method X, test B already counts that method X has been called.

[image]

```js
it('should update only perm and name', async () => {
  const spyOnPerm = jest.spyOn(Group.prototype, 'changePermissions');
  const spyOnName = jest.spyOn(Group.prototype, 'changeName');
  const spyOnIsDpt = jest.spyOn(Group.prototype, 'changeIsDepartment');
  const command = new ChangeGroupPermissionCommand({
    group,
    propsToChange: {
      permissions: [Permission.createFromBitmap('@iam.11111111')],
      name: 'new name' + Math.random(),
    },
  });
  await context.run(author, async () => {
     await handler.execute(command);
     expect(spyOnPerm).toBeCalledTimes(1);
     expect(spyOnName).toBeCalledTimes(1);
     expect(spyOnIsDpt).not.toBeCalled();
  });
});

it('should update only department status', async () => {
  const spyOnPermission = jest.spyOn(Group.prototype, 'changePermissions');
  const spyOnName = jest.spyOn(Group.prototype, 'changeName');
  const spyOnIsDpt = jest.spyOn(Group.prototype, 'changeIsDepartment');

  const command = new ChangeGroupPermissionCommand({
    group,
    propsToChange: {
      isDepartment: true,
    },
  });
  await context.run(author, async () => {
    await handler.execute(command);
    expect(spyOnPermission).not.toBeCalled();
    expect(spyOnName).not.toBeCalled();
    expect(spyOnIsDpt).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that :

```
afterEach(() => {    
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```